# The keystrokes Shift + Alt + Down + ( Any Arrow) doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I can't get this combination to work in [VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It doesn't come from the preconfigured shortcuts because I've already looked at it. I also checked with Gnome Tweaks in the Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options menu. Nothing is checked.

By testing the combination with the virtual keyboard I see that the arrows never activate.

Comment: I don't know what VCS is but, what's your keyboard? Not all of them allow more than 3 key press at once ([3KRO, 3-key rollover](https://superuser.com/a/1445225/500826)). Test [here](https://keyboardchecker.com/) or [here](https://www.xem.us/rollover/rollover.html). Are you sure an action is configured with that trigger

Comment: VSC* Visual Studio code (sorry)
You are right when i try on the site you give the arrow doesn't work.
How come it work on windows on the VSC?

Comment: If a 4 simultaneous keystroke doesn't work on Linux shouldn't work on Windows wither, is a hardware limitation

Answer (score 0):

Not all keyboards allow more than 3 key press at once ([3KRO, 3-key rollover](https://superuser.com/a/1445225/500826)):

> What you're referring to is called rollover or key rollover. This simply refers to a computer's ability to correctly handle several simultaneous keystrokes.
>
> *X-key rollover* refers to how many keys you can press down at once, while still being registered by the computer.

Test [here](https://www.xem.us/rollover/rollover.html) or [here](https://keyboardchecker.com/).

Luckly, VSC (try better [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/.)) usually [doesn't need more](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) (more [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)).